# Google Calendar API rate limits

Tags: google-calendar-api

How a Google Calendar API "rate limit" counts for an account?

Is it a one value which separates between every service accounts in a Google account
or it individual for each service account?

E.g. Rate limit for a Google account is 100 and, if Google account has 2 service accounts, which rate limit value would have each of them: 50 or 100?